# Need have jq output with its key as well

Tags: json, key, jq

Currently with below json,

```
$ cat input.json

{
  "shipping": {
    "local": true,
    "us": true,
    "us_rate": {
      "amount": "0.00",
      "currency": "USD",
      "symbol": "$"
    }
  }
}
```

I can simply get the `us_rate`

```
$ cat input.json |jq .shipping.us_rate
{
  "amount": "0.00",
  "currency": "USD",
  "symbol": "$"
}
```

But I want to include its key as well as:

```
{
  "us_rate": {
    "amount": "0.00",
    "currency": "USD",
    "symbol": "$"
  }
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or just:

```
.shipping | {us_rate}
```

using the abbreviation `{foo}` for `{"foo": .foo}` when `.foo` is allowed.

Comment: Thanks, that's better and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question.

```
cat input.json |jq '.shipping | {us_rate: .us_rate}'
```